# Template for glass slides 2 x 2.5 cm

Tags: templates

I am a scientist and I want to label glass slides and I need a template. I would like to have  rows of 2x2.5 cm rectangle boxes in which I write my labels and which I can print on a4 paper. I tried to come up with some by myself; I failed. Please help me.

Comment: What does "glass slides" refer to? Physical glass?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tikz` and a `\foreach` loop:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\MyBox}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick, yshift=-#1] (0,0) rectangle (2.5cm, 2.0cm);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
\foreach \Y in {0, ..., 9} {%
    \noindent
    \foreach \X in {1, ..., 4} {%
        \MyBox{\Y}
    }%
    \par%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey that is really way better than everything I came up with yet. I will try to use that. Do you have an idea on how I can use it to directly label every single box in a defined way?

Comment: @Jan: How do you want to specify the labels to be used for each of the boxes? as a list, or are they to be programmatically generated based on the location of the box?  Where do you want the label in the box? Bottom left? centered?